# DryIoc 3.0 Castle Interceptor

Tags: dryioc

The recommended way to use interception in DryIoc doesn't work anymore since 3.0:

https://bitbucket.org/dadhi/dryioc/wiki/Interception

The Method "GetPublicInstanceConstructors" is missing.
What is the new way to achive this?

Comment: Need to update docs :(

Comment: Meanwhile gere is working example from the repo: https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/bd068a910a60837e3b0e870cc6ea29394c3aeac7/Net45/DryIoc.IssuesTests/Interception/DryIocInterception.cs

Answer (score 1):

```
Made.Of((Type type) => type.GetConstructors().SingleOrDefault(c => c.GetParameters().Length != 0)
```

Seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [working integration code](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/test/DryIoc.IssuesTests/Interception/DryIocInterception.cs) (which probably will be moved to separate package in future):

```
using System;
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
using ImTools;

namespace DryIoc.Interception
{
    // Extension methods for interceptor registration using Castle Dynamic Proxy.
    public static class DryIocInterception
    {
        public static void Intercept<TService, TInterceptor>(this IRegistrator registrator, object serviceKey = null)
            where TInterceptor : class, IInterceptor => 
            registrator.Intercept<TInterceptor>(typeof(TService), serviceKey);

        public static void Intercept<TInterceptor>(this IRegistrator registrator, Type serviceType, object serviceKey = null)
            where TInterceptor : class, IInterceptor =>
            registrator.Intercept(serviceType, Parameters.Of.Type(typeof(IInterceptor[]), typeof(TInterceptor[])), serviceKey);

        public static void Intercept(this IRegistrator registrator,
            Type serviceType, ParameterSelector interceptorsParameterSelector, object serviceKey = null)
        {
            Type proxyType;
            if (serviceType.IsInterface())
                proxyType = ProxyBuilder.CreateInterfaceProxyTypeWithTargetInterface(
                    serviceType, ArrayTools.Empty<Type>(), ProxyGenerationOptions.Default);
            else if (serviceType.IsClass())
                proxyType = ProxyBuilder.CreateClassProxyTypeWithTarget(
                    serviceType, ArrayTools.Empty<Type>(), ProxyGenerationOptions.Default);
            else
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    $"Intercepted service type {serviceType} is not a supported, cause it is nor a class nor an interface");

            registrator.Register(serviceType, proxyType,
                made: Made.Of(
                    pt => pt.PublicConstructors().FindFirst(ctor => ctor.GetParameters().Length != 0),
                    interceptorsParameterSelector),
                setup: Setup.DecoratorOf(useDecorateeReuse: true, decorateeServiceKey: serviceKey));
        }

        private static DefaultProxyBuilder ProxyBuilder => _proxyBuilder ?? (_proxyBuilder = new DefaultProxyBuilder());
        private static DefaultProxyBuilder _proxyBuilder;
    }
}
```